# High Frequency radio wave propagation time

Tags: electromagnetism, radio, radio-frequency

What is the maximum time for an HF radio wave to reach its destination regardless of propagation mode? Since electromagnetic waves' speed is close to the light speed in the air, can we say it is always lower than e.g. 1 second? Or, atmospheric conditions, reflection etc. may cause it to be as long as 10 seconds or more?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it will typically depend on how far it is propagating.

Comment: It takes longer if taking the long route around the earth. Earth/Moon/Earth bounce signals also take longer. Not 10 seconds though.

Comment: Light speed travles around the world in 0.13 seconds so even if it takes the long route can we say 0.13 is the maximum value? I can't be sure because of reflections from Ionosphere and ground.

Comment: Say a radio wave can travel around the world 5 times. Is it possible to pass destination point in round 1 and reach it in round 2. In this case maximum value will be 0.13x2=0.26 seconds. If it propagate reflecting from surfaces this will be much longer.